# My JavaScript object value reset function is getting out of hand

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I have a Form class (quite a lot [like this](https://github.com/laracasts/Vue-Forms/blob/9ccf969dfda9ca6dcc1026699315188e651bafb8/public/js/app.js#L67)) whose form fields are dynamically set. Here's an example fieldset:

**Example form object dataset**

```
jamb_style: '',
cutouts: '',
door: {
    length: '',
    width: '',
    thickness: '',
},
lock_bore: {
    location: '',
    diameter: '',
},
hinge: {
    size: '',
    pocket_radius: '',
    backset: '',
    locations: {
        first: '',
        second: '',
        third: '',
        fourth: '',
    },
},
face_plate: {
    length: '',
    width: '',
    radius: '',
},
```

As you can see some fields are nested and others aren't, if everything sat on one level then resetting the form would be trivial:

**Trivially reset a field in a flat form object**

```
reset() {
    for (let field in this.originalData) {
        this[field] = '';
    }
}
```

However, because some of my form data are objects *my* `reset()` function looks like this:

**Warning, what you are about to see may disturb you**

```
reset() {
    let data = this.originalData;

    for (let key in data) {
        if (typeof data[key] === 'object') {
            let subData = data[key];

            for (let subKey in subData) {
                if (typeof subData[subKey] === 'object') {
                    let subDataData = data[key][subKey];

                    for (let subKeyKey in subDataData) {
                        if (typeof data[key][subKey][subKeyKey] === 'string') {
                            this[key][subKey][subKeyKey] = '';
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (typeof subData[subKey] === 'string') {
                    this[key][subKey] = '';
                }
            }
        }

        if (typeof data[key] === 'string') {
            this[key] = '';
        }
    }
}
```

What I'd really like is a way to clean this up by making this function recursive, so that it drills down and ensures that a property is only cleared when it is not an object.

The problem is I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: where is this `recursive` function you claim is getting out of hand? You have not posted anything that is recursive, so, it's hard to help you with your alleged issue

Comment: Recursion would be if the function calls itself, that's not the case here, is it?

Comment: The reason it's getting out of hand is because it's *not* recursive. As you can see from the answer, a recursive version is much simpler.

Comment: You are right, I updated the question to make it more accurate: what I desired was recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing it recursively using the following code as baseline

```
function resetObject(objectToReset){
 Object.keys(objectToReset).forEach(function(key){
   if(Object.keys(objectToReset[key]).length<=1){
       objectToReset[key]='';
   }else{
      resetObject(objectToReset[key]);
   }
  });
}
resetObject(object);
```

The above code is trying to loop through all keys of the provided object and reset it once it identifies this to be a single key value pair and calls itself if it identifies the key to contain as sub object in it.

Hope this helps to extend it to your own idea. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

A novel way of resetting your object is to keep a reference to your 'clean' form and clone it.

e.g

```js
  const formTemplate = { //Abridged for brevity
  cutouts: '',
  hinge: {
      size: '',
      pocket_radius: '',
      backset: '',
      locations: {
          first: '',
          second: '',
          third: '',
          fourth: '',
      },
  },
}

function getNewForm(form){
 return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(form));
}

console.assert(getNewForm(formTemplate)!==formTemplate); //Assert new form is not equal by reference
console.assert(JSON.stringify(getNewForm(formTemplate))===JSON.stringify(formTemplate)); //Assert new form is equal by value
```